# Ubuntu 19.10 not finding new hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, 19.10

A couple of months ago I installed Ubuntu 19.10 onto my dad's new laptop. He's since installed a new mechanical hard drive. For some reason the system is not recognising that it has been installed. How can he, who is completely new to Linux, get his system to recognise that the new hard drive exists?

This is something that's beyond my skill set, at the moment.

Comment: you don't see any drives when you do dmesg | grep '/dev/sd' ?

Comment: I think you can also do: sudo blkid

Comment: _lsblk | grep -v  loop   && df -h | grep -v loop_ will show the drive devices. Also, was the drive 'new in box' or had it been used in Windows before? Windows 7 had a 'dynamic' drive partition which Linux can't see.

Comment: Get a gparted Live CD / USB and set up the partitions first.  Then it will be ok. OR from Ubuntu you can try gparted and it may see the drive where the file explorers will not.

Comment: I've given this link to my dad but, unfortunately, he does not understand most of what has been said so far. He can say, though, about the hard-drive:

"The Laptop has two IDE SSDs. Added was a 1TB HDD – new from manufacturer; never been used."

Comment: My dad has looked at these answers but he's not able to understand the various terms and I'm not able to explain it to him (I'm not a teacher). Is there a easier way he can do this?